# Google Cloud build and private Nuget repository

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, nuget, nuget-package

I have a private NuGet repository created with BaGet.
My software is hosted in Google Cloud where there is also the Git repository with my code.
I have some Cloud build triggers that run the build in the cloud and automatically deploy the applications.
I have created some NuGet package with my projects and now I need to change the reference from code (project reference) to NuGet package reference in my private repository.
Locally all works, but now I need to do the same in my Google Cloud build trigger and I don't know where I can specify the reference to my private repository.
My build script is a yaml file but inside I don't have a reference to the standard NuGet repository and I don't know how I can specify an additional NuGet package repository for some libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet reads configuration from [nuget.config files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file). In fact, it reads from [multiple config files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior). So you can commit a nuget.config to your source code repository, and therefore anyone else who clones your repo (even a CI agent) doesn't need to be configured, it "Just Works".

The part of the config that's relevant to your question is the [`<packageSources>` section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-sections), so a minimal config with only package sources defined is:

```xml
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- make sure other nuget.config files don't add unexpected sources -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="private" value="https://my-server/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```